# App crashes when starting, right after I downloaded it from Play Store

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-play

My app was working fine, but after I downloaded it from playstore, it does not even start the first screen. it crushes. I have looked all over for the solution but with no luck. Someone please help me out. This is the error that I am getting.

```
    2020-09-16 15:32:35.002 2354-2687/? E/libPowerStretch: LucidStats currentFPS = 21.31 [1946146032]
2020-09-16 15:32:35.019 3177-13224/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
2020-09-16 15:32:35.264 2067-2358/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
        at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.enforceWritePermission(SettingsProvider.java:1777)
        at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.mutateSecureSetting(SettingsProvider.java:1242)
        at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.insertSecureSetting(SettingsProvider.java:1202)
        at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:368)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:403)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:272)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying it was working fine before. so, did you check the signed app? before publishing to playstore?

it seems maybe some proguard rule made some of your class obfuscate and thats why its crashing...

could you please provide some more information regarding this app.